# Violation of PRIMARY KEY constraint Error when insert item in MVC

Tags: asp.net-mvc, entity-framework

This is my class

```
public class SmartPhone : BaseEntity
{
    [MaxLength(50, ErrorMessage = "Maximum length 50 character"), MinLength(1, ErrorMessage = "Min length 1 character")]
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public decimal Price { get; set; }
    public virtual Manufacture Manufacture { get; set; }
}
```

and this class has foreign key with `Manufacture`. I use EF

```
public class Manufacture : BaseEntity
{
    [Required]
    [MaxLength(50, ErrorMessage = "The Manufacture Name must be a string and max length 50")]
    public string ManufactureName { get; set; }
    public virtual ICollection<SmartPhone> SmartPhones { get; set; }
}
```

when I use mapper to my DTo object

```
var mapper1 = Mapper.CreateMap<SmartPhoneDto, SmartPhone>();
mapper1.ForMember(d => d.Manufacture, s => s.MapFrom(a => a.ManufactureDto));

var mapper = Mapper.CreateMap<SmartPhone, SmartPhoneDto>();
mapper.ForMember(d => d.ManufactureDto, s => s.MapFrom(a => a.Manufacture));
```

And am insert into my database it crash when `SaveChanges` is called:

> Violation of PRIMARY KEY constraint 'PK_dbo.Manufactures'. Cannot insert duplicate key in object 'dbo.Manufactures'.

Please help me solve it

Comment: What does your manufacturer database schematic look like?

Comment: Can you give us the information about how the primary keys are defined in your model?